# Indirect initialization of memory via UnsafeMutablePointer types

Tags: objective-c, swift

I encountered an unfamiliar pattern of initialization from `Objective-C` that I'm struggling to replicate in Swift.

#### Objective-C

In the example code, they defined a C struct such as this (abbreviated, original [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQPlayback/PlayingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH3-SW1)):

```
struct AQPlayerState {
  AudioFileID mAudioFile;
}
```

Here's an example that uses `AQPlayerState`:

```
AQPlayerState aqData; // 1
OSStattus result = 
  AudioFileOpenURL(
    audioFileURL,
    fsRdPerm,
    0,
    &aqData.mAudioFile // 2
  );
```

The key takeaway from above is that `aqData` currently has uninitialized properties, and `AudioFileOpenURL` is initializing `aqData.mAudioFile` on it's behalf.

### Swift

I'm trying to replicate this behaviour in Swift. Here's what I've tried so far:

#### Models:

```
class Person {
  var name: String 

  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

class Foo {
  var person: Person?
}
```

My idea was to replicate the Objective-C code by passing a reference of `Foo.person` into a function that would instantiate it on it's behalf.

#### Initialization Function:

```
func initializeWithBob(_ ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Person?>) {
  ptr.pointee = Person(name: "Bob")
}
```

`initializeWithBob` takes a pointer to an address for a `Person?` type and initializes it with a `Person(name: "Bob")` object.

Here's my test code:

```
let foo = Foo()
let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Person?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
ptr.initialize(to: foo.person)
defer {
  ptr.deinitialize()
  ptr.deallocate(capacity: 1)
}

initializeWithBob(ptr)
print(foo.person) // outputs nil
```

`initializeWithBob` failed to "install" an instance of type `Person` in my `Foo` instance. I presume some of my assumptions are wrong. Looking for help in correcting my assumptions and understanding of this situation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Person?> = .allocate(capacity: 1)` it is not a valid syntax. You mean `let ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Person?> = .allocate(capacity: 1)`

Comment: You haven't initialized person. It is actually nil. What did you expect? try adding `foo.person = Person(name: "Kelvin Lau")` before calling setup

Comment: @LeoDabus Fixed, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @LeoDabus Calling `foo.person = Person(name: "Kelvin Lau")` defeats the purpose of me trying to mock the Objective-C pattern of initialization.

Comment: why would you think ptr would not be released once setup method is finished?

Comment: @LeoDabus Added `deinitialize` and `deallocate` calls. Was that what you meant?

Comment: you need to assign it to person `foo.person = ptr.pointee`

Comment: `func setup(foo: Foo) {
    let ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Person?> = .allocate(capacity: 1)
    ptr.initialize(to: foo.person)
    defer {
        ptr.deinitialize()
        ptr.deallocate(capacity: 1)
    }
    initialize(ptr)
    foo.person = ptr.pointee
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, but is there another way to achieve that, without having a reference to the original `foo` object?

The Objective-C call did not have a reference to `AQPlayer`, but was able to initialize the `mAudioFile` property inside `AQPlayer` via a pointer to the property.

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't think `inout` will change the situation. `Foo` is a class, and has reference semantics.

Comment: sorry I forgot it was a class not a struct thats why I deleted my comment before your reply

Comment: @LeoDabus No problem. I'm going to edit my question a bit to be more clear. Thanks for the discussion so far!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you are looking for via [withUnsafeMutablePointer(to:_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2429788-withunsafemutablepointer) like so:

```
let foo = Foo()

withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &foo.person) { (ptr) -> Void in
    initializeWithBob(ptr)
}

print(foo.person!.name) // outputs Bob
```

However, I wouldn't recommend this approach. IMHO it makes more sense to wrap the APIs you are working with in a C function that you can make 'nice' to call from Swift. The problem with your current approach is that this type of Swift is hard to read for Swift developers and also hard to read for Audio Toolbox developers.

Comment: Works! What is the difference between `withUnsafeMutablePointer` and creating an `UnsafeMutablePointer` using `allocate` and `initialize`?

Answer (score 0):

@kelvinlau Is this what you were thinking of trying to achieve?

```
func initializeWithBob(_ ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Foo>) {
    ptr.pointee.person = Person(name: "Bob")
}

let foo = Foo()
let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Foo>.allocate(capacity: 1)
ptr.initialize(to: foo)

initializeWithBob(ptr)
print(foo.person?.name ?? "nil")
ptr.deinitialize()
ptr.deallocate(capacity: 1)
print(foo.person?.name ?? "nil")
```

Comment: Not quite. The `UnsafeMutablePointer` needs to point directly at the `person` property, not the `Foo` object that has a reference to `person`.

Answer (score 0):

The code pattern you have in Objective-C is for *out parameters*, that is parameters which return a value, or *in out parameters*, that is parameters which both pass a value in and return one. Objective-C does not directly support these so pointers are used to produce the semantics.

Swift has *in out* parameters indicated by the keyword `inout` in the function declaration. Within the function an assignment to an `inout` parameters effectively assigns a value to the variable that was passed as the argument. At the function call site the variable must be prefixed by `&` to indicate it is the variable itself and not its value which is effectively being passed.

Keeping your `Person` and `Foo` as is your function becomes:

```
func initializeWithBob(_ ptr: inout Person?)
{
   ptr = Person(name: "Bob")
}
```

and it may be used, for example, like:

```
var example = Foo()
initializeWithBob(&example.person)
```

Using `inout` in Swift is better than trying to build the same semantics using pointers.

HTH

---

*Note*: **You can skip this unless you are curious**

"Effectively" was used a few times above. Typically *out* parameters are implemented by the parameter passing method *call-by-result*, while *in out* use *call-by-value-result*. Using either of these methods the returned value is only assigned to the passed variable at the point the function returns.

Another parameter passing method is *call-by-reference*, which is similar to *call-by-value-result* **except** that each and every assignment to the parameter within the function is immediately made to passed variable. This means changes to the passed variable may be visible *before* the function returns.

Swift by design does not specify whether its `inout` uses call-by-value-result or call-by-reference. So rather than specify the exact semantics in the answer "effectively" is used.